# Customize data types in a generated model with hibernate

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate

I have a Spring/Hibernate application with the following domain class (irrelevant code stripped for brevity):

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Program implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long tid;

    @Column
    @Convert(converter = ProgramStatusConverter.class)
    private ProgramStatus status;

    @Column
    @Length(max=64)
    private String containerId;

    @Column
    private String sourceCode;

    @Column
    private String compilationOutput;

    @Column
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="program")
    private Set<Execution> executions;
}
```

The problem is that the database schema (currently an in-memory h2 database) is generated when I startup the application. It works fine in almost all cases, but the "compilationOutput" and "sourceCode" columns are generated as VARCHAR(255), which is too short.

The solution I used was simply to add `@Length(max=10000)` on the two columns, but I don't like the solution for two reasons:

- It's a semantic annotation and I'm using it to solve a purely technical issue. I have absolutely no reason to limit these fields to 10000 characters.
- What if I get a sourceCode that's longer than 10000 characters ? This solution is not a real solution.

Is there a better way ?

Comment: "database schema (currently an in-memory h2 database) is generated when I startup the application" Is there no way of addressing this from the database side? To pick up a permanent schema?

Comment: @h.j.k. I could, but for the moment my application is still a simple proof-of-concept and I don't want to bother creating a database server or writing SQL script that will do exactly what hibernate does (almost-)perfectly well.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112667/issue-persisting-long-strings-with-hibernate. Either `@Column(columnDefinition="text")` or `@Type(type="text")` could work for you.

Comment: @ferada: Thanks ! That's what I wanted. Funny thing, in H2 the column type end up being VARCHAR(2147483647).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not unreasonable that a maximum length should be specified for a field that is backed by a `VARCHAR`. In some frameworks, for example Django (Python), a `max_length` parameter is mandatory to create a `CharField`, but optional for a `TextField`. This makes sense: how else can the framework know the size of the column. A `VARCHAR` column needs a max size.

Make the maximum size a conscious design decision when using a relational database as storage. If the data is text and you need to support arbitrary length, then in the database it should be stored as a `TEXT` field instead of a `VARCHAR`. For that, use `@Column(columnDefinition="text")` or `@Type(type="text")`, as [@ferada](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/54571/ferada) said in a comment,
and as discussed in this related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112667/issue-persisting-long-strings-with-hibernate).

You remarked in a comment that H2 used the type `VARCHAR(2147483647)`.
That's an irrelevant implementation detail of how H2 supports `TEXT` type.
It's indeed a bit funny.